# Scraping all comments from specific site

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape all comments from all pages of a specific article. For example this article: [Link](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/syrien-die-islamisten-sind-aleppos-letzte-hoffnung-a-1105806.html)

I think the comments are in javascript, could anyone help me figure out how I can scrape all comments?

This is the code I use

```
def getSpiegelComments(url):
    try:
        html = urlopen(url)
    except HTTPError as e:
        print(e)
        return None
    try:
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        comments = bsObj.findAll("div", {"class": "article-comment"})
    except AttributeError as e:
        return None
    for comment in comments:
        yield comment

url = 'http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/syrien-die-islamisten-sind-aleppos-letzte-hoffnung-a-1105806.html'
comments = getSpiegelComments(url)

if comments == None:
    print("Comments could not be found on " + url)
else:
    for comment in comments:
        print(comment)
```

I need all comments (currently 124) from all pages. Not only the 5 comments from the first page.

Comment: The url no longer works. Please update it.

Comment: Done, you can check now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the text is available after each *div.article-comment-title* under the divs with the class *js-article-post-full-text*:

```
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/syrien-die-islamisten-sind-aleppos-letzte-hoffnung-a-1105806.html").content)

for comm in soup.select("div.article-comment-title"):
    print(comm.a.text)
    print(comm.find_next("div","js-article-post-full-text").text)
```

To get all 120+, you can use the url `http://www.spiegel.de/fragments/community/spon-495132-{}.html` passing in the offset  number to start from:

```
import re

def yield_comments(soup):
    for comm in soup.select("div.article-comment-title"):
        yield comm.a.text.strip(),comm.find_next("div", "js-article-post-full-text").text.strip()


next_url = "http://www.spiegel.de/fragments/community/spon-495132-{}.html"
url = "http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/syrien-die-islamisten-sind-aleppos-letzte-hoffnung-a-1105806.html"


with requests.Session() as s:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content)
    # get total comments
    tot = re.search("\d+",soup.select_one("#js-article-comments-box-pager").find_previous_sibling("span").text)
    tot = int(tot.group())
    # get comments from first page
    for title, com in yield_comments(soup):
        print(title, com)
    # start at the 6th comment until the end
    for page in range(6, tot, 5):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(next_url.format(page)).content)
        for title, com in yield_comments(soup):
            print(title, com)
```

That will give you comments all the way to 124:

```
.......................................
(u'117. Horst John', u'Zitat von Horst JohnAl-Sham, Al-Nusra usw. sind Nachfolger der Al qaida. Diese als Befreier zu sehen ist der blanke Hohn. Schauen sie nur die youtube Videos diese langb\xe4rtigen gekauften Terrorbande sich an. Waffendepots in Krankenh\xe4user und Schulen, Bombenattacken auf Fl\xfcchtlingscamps sind das Werk dieser Terroristen.\r\n\r\nWer sieht die denn hier oder auf SPON als Befreier? das steht ja nur, das das die letzte Hoffnung ist. Und so wird es sich wahrscheinlich auch f\xfcr die dort hungernden Menschen anf\xfchlen.')
(u'118. Verantwortung', u"Die viel naheliegendere Frage ist, warum ein Umsturzversuch, egal aus welcher Motivation heraus, der hunderttausende Tote gefordert, Millionen Menschen vertrieben und ein ganzes Land in eine Tr\xfcmmerlandschaft verwandelt hat, nicht l\xe4ngst vor Jahren abgebrochen wurde. \r\nDie Antwort ist bekannt und hat mit einer weiteren Frage zu tun:\r\n\r\nWieso fand sich die Bundesrepublik in einer Gemeinschaft der 'Freunde Syriens' mit Saudi-Arabien, Katar und der T\xfcrkei wieder, die nun beim besten Willen mit Demokratie in Syrien nichts zu tun hatten, die aber sp\xe4testens seit anfang 2012 flei\xdfig Waffen nach Syrien pumpten?\r\nhttp://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2013/03/25/world/middleeast/an-arms-pipeline-to-the-syrian-rebels.html?ref=middleeast&_r=0")
(u'119. @ Piece', u'Zitat von Pieceich war bisher nicht als Kommentator bei SPON registriert, aber der hier publizierte Artikel ist derart nah an der Grenze zur islamistischen Propaganda, dass ich mich einer scharfen Protestnote nicht erwehren kann:\r\nWie um alles in der Welt ist es m\xf6glich radikalste Islamisten als "letzte Hoffnung f\xfcr Aleppo" derart offen zu glorifizieren? \r\n\r\nUnter gr\xf6\xdftem Wohlwollen verbleiben als Motivation f\xfcr diese Zeilen zwei M\xf6glichkeiten:\r\n\r\n1.Dem Autor dieses Artikels ist nicht bekannt welche Konsequenzen ein Sieg dieser "Freiheitsk\xe4mpfer" f\xfcr die Zivilbev\xf6lkerung nach sich z\xf6ge. \r\n\r\n2. Die Konsequenzen sind bekannt, werden jedoch als weniger schwerwiegend erachtet.\r\n\r\nBeides disqualifiziert den Autor im SPON zu publizieren.\r\n\r\n\r\nWas die wahren Motive der Dschihadisten (Stichwort: menschliche Schutzschilde usw.) anbetrifft, ganz zu schweigen.\r\n\r\nEs gibt noch eine Dritte M\xf6glichkeit: Sie haben den Autor nicht verstanden. Er hat sich keineswegs mit den Terroristen gemein gemacht, sondern lediglich versucht, die Gef\xfchlslage der dort eingeschlossenen Menschen nachzuvollziehen. Aber da m\xfcsste man dann nat\xfcrlich mal genauer lesen und auch noch mitdenken.')
(u'120. Die letzte Hofnung', u'Islamisten die letzte, im wahrsten Sinne des Wortes,\r\nHoffnung. Sind nicht die Islamisten und andere Rebellen der Grund daf\xfcr, dass die Bev\xf6lkerung so tief in der ...\r\nsitzt. Von wem wird dieser Schreiber eigentlich gesponsert.')
(u'121. @jethan', u'Zitat von jethaneigentlich islamische Terroristen, sind der Grund und der Ausl\xf6ser dieser Katastrophe.\r\nSie jetzt als Retter zu pr\xe4sentieren ist blanker Hohn gegen\xfcber der betroffenen Bev\xf6lkerung.\r\nDie h\xe4tte l\xe4ngst durch die Korridore die Stadt verlassen k\xf6nnen, w\xe4re sie nicht von den Terroristen, ja genau, denselben die sich jetzt als Retter feiern lassen, daran gehindert worden.\r\n\r\nDer Ausl\xf6ser ist Assat selbst: Er hat friedliche Demonstrationen mit Panzern niederwalzen lassen. DAS war der Beginn. Weitere Proteste der Bev\xf6lkerung gegen dieses Vorgehen folgte auf dem Fu\xdfe. Daraufhin lie\xdf Assat massiv seine Armee gegen die Demonstranten einsetzen.\r\n\r\nDas schaukelte sich dann soweit hoch, das teils ein machtvakuum entstand. Erst jetzt traten fanatische Islamisten auf den Plan.\r\n\r\nSie ignorieren die ganze Vorgeschichte.')
(u'122.', u'Zitat von jowittIch weis nicht, was Sie haben. In dem Artikel steht nichts davon, das die angreifenden Islamisten "gut" seien. Im gegenteil: Dort wird beschrieben, das sie einen "Gottesstaat" nach der Scharia wollen.\r\n\r\nNehmen Sie eigentlich alles so w\xf6rtlich? Dank zahlreicher Stilmittel l\xe4sst sich ein Text nicht nur interessant gestalten, manche lassen sich auch hervorragend dazu verwenden einen unterbewussten Eindruck beim Leser haften zu lassen. Propaganda egal welcher politischen Seite funktioniert auch oft auf die gleiche Art.\r\n\r\nDie "Rebellen" (stimme f\xfcr Unwort des Jahres in dieser Verwendung) l\xe4sst der Autor im Artikel an vielen Stellen tats\xe4chlich so dastehen als w\xfcrden diese nur den Zivilisten helfen wollen. Das wird so explizit nicht klar genannt, erschlie\xdft sich jedoch aus Wortwahl, Inhalt und Zusammenhang. W\xfcrde man in der Presse das offen so schreiben, w\xfcrde man hinterher definitiv darauf festgenagelt werden. Suchen Sie den Link des Mitkommentators zur ZON Meldung raus, nachdem die Rebellen die Zivilisten nicht aus der Stadt lassen. Dann vergleichen Sie den Inhalt dieses Artikels mit den vorliegenden Fakten, gerne auch auf den BBC News Seiten, die in dem Fall auch wesentlich objektiver sind. Das macht es u. U. leichter nachzuvollziehen, was der Vorposter gemeint hat.\r\n\r\nDie Rebellen, komischerweise tats\xe4chlich nicht Terroristen genannt obwohl die Definition passt, werden von Anfang an auf SPON und einigen anderen Nachrichtenseiten sehr besch\xf6nigend in den Artikeln abgebildet, \xe4hnlich der neuen Kiewer Regierung oder in weiten Teilen auch Erdogan. Da muss man noch nicht einmal auf RT oder \xe4hnliche Seiten, um das als Bl\xf6dsinn auszufiltern, da reichen ganz normale, objektive Nachrichten ohne Meinungsbildung alla BILD.')
(u'123. Guter Bericht', u'Danke f\xfcr diesen Bericht zur Lage in Syrien. \r\n\r\nUnd auch etwas zum Nachdenken: Wenn wir (die freien Demokratien) nicht helfen, aber radikale Islamisten, wird da nicht die H\xe4lfte Bev\xf6lkerung Syriens - immerhin mehr als 10 Millionen Menschen - den Islamisten geradezu in die Arme getrieben? Unterlassene Hilfeleistung wird bestraft. aj')
(u'124. Unterst\xfctzung von Extremisten', u'Zitat von jowittIch weis nicht, was Sie haben. In dem Artikel steht nichts davon, das die angreifenden Islamisten "gut" seien. Im gegenteil: Dort wird beschrieben, das sie einen "Gottesstaat" nach der Scharia wollen.\r\n\r\nWas steht in der \xdcberschrift?\r\n"Belagerte Stadt in Syrien: Die Islamisten sind Aleppos letzte Hoffnung"\r\nund weiter geht\'s:\r\n"W\xe4hrend die USA und Europa zusehen, wie Hunderttausende Menschen in Aleppo ausgehungert werden, kommen Islamisten den Eingeschlossenen zur Hilfe. Angef\xfchrt werden sie von einer Terrormiliz."\r\n\r\nWie w\xfcrden Sie denn diese SPON Einf\xfchrung interpretieren?\r\nEs steht doch w\xf6rtlich da - eine Terrormiliz kommt den Eingeschlossenen zu Hilfe und ist Hoffnung, sogar letzte Hoffnung.\r\n\'Hilfe\' assoziiere ich immer noch mit \'etwas Gutes leisten\'.\r\nEs steht im Text dann auch an keiner Stelle, da\xdf diese Hilfe vom Autor irgendwie ablehnt wird. \r\nWie auch an keiner Stelle belegt ist, da\xdf die Bev\xf6lkerung diese Hilfe \xfcberhaupt haben will, das aber nur nebenbei.\r\n\r\nEntweder der SPON Autor hat sich hier semantisch vertan, oder er hat sich als Unterst\xfctzer von Extremisten geouted.')
```

Comment: Thx for your solution. Where did you find that URL: http://www.spiegel.de/fragments/community/spon-495132-{}.html ?

Comment: Good day dear Padraic - many many thanks for this great solution. Tried to re-capitulate and to learn form this. But unfortunatly it does not work here (any more) with a simple Spiegel.de - article. 

Any chance to show a simple example of a spiegel.de - scraper that works for nowadays - and in these days!? this could be great for my learning curve - thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should be scraping from [this link](http://www.spiegel.de/forum/politik/belagerte-stadt-syrien-die-islamisten-sind-aleppos-letzte-hoffnung-thread-495132-1.html) instead of the one you provided because its where the actual comments are coming from and this way it allows you to escape the javascript on the URL you posted that's hiding the comments you want.

If you scrape from this link, getting ALL the comments should be simple because, conveniently, each of the pages here have the same "base" URL (`http://www.spiegel.de/forum/politik/belagerte-stadt-syrien-die-islamisten-sind-aleppos-letzte-hoffnung-thread-495132-`) and then the page number is added on at the end as `1.html`, `2.html` and so on.

This means in your code you will want to loop through each of these pages. Here is some pseudo code to help you get started.

```
def comment_spider(max_pages): 
    page = 1 #start on page 1

    comments_list = []

    while page <= max_pages:

        url = 'http://www.spiegel.de/forum/politik/belagerte-stadt-syrien-die-islamisten-sind-aleppos-letzte-hoffnung-thread-495132-'+str(page)+'.html'

        req = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = req.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "lxml")

        for items in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'comment'}): #you need to get the actual information for this yourself
            comment = items.get_text()
            comments_list.append(comment)

        page += 1
    return comments_list
```

Then to call this function you would give it the total number of pages. E.g.

```
comment_spider(13)
```